# Post one JSON object as value in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I need to post only one json object as value.

Here is my code:

```
let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
"data": ["user_token":"firebase_token"]
]
```

This code output is:

```
["user_token": "f4Vv2GLobhY:APA91bGz5b8M4pTqHnEeATeDSbQeq9T1VJYMS8mdX3OunJwgu5plfqVDsjYGxnNda22Drbmq7fXYyCSW1_4K69sq8kqK8hgpKbB2KuBAMGlPL-SIC8xWfazby-RnrdmBKQR6fpU8_1K_"]
```

The problem I'm facing is that the server wont accept this parameter because it's an array
the string should not be `"[ ....` .
but should be: `"{ ...`

So when I try to modify my code to this:

```
let jsonObject: [String: Any] = "data": {"user_token":"firebase_token"}
```

To give me the desired output I get compiler errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "it's an array", no, that's not an array. In Swift, "[" might be the start of an array or a dictionary. In JSON, "[" is the start of an array. The question is: Where did you convert your Swift Dictionary into JSON? Where is your Request creation?

Comment: Also, structs that implements Codable could have been a solution

Answer (score 0):

Change your type to dictionary of dictionary like

```
let jsonObject: [String:[String: String]]
```

and then encode it

```
let jsonObject: [String:[String: String]] = ["data": ["user_token":"firebase_token"]]
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let data = try encoder.encode(jsonObject)
```